# Multiplying values from two different dictionaries together in Python

Tags: python, matrix-multiplication, dictionary

I have two separate dictionaries with keys and values that I would like to multiply together. The values should be multiplied just by the keys that they have.

i.e.

```
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dict2 = {'a': 15, 'b': 10, 'd': 17}

dict3 = dict.items() * dict.items()
print dict3

#### #dict3 should equal 
{'a': 15, 'b': 20}
```

If anyone could help, that would be great. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

You can use a [dict comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
>>> {k : v * dict2[k] for k, v in dict1.items() if k in dict2}
{'a': 15, 'b': 20}
```

Or, in pre-2.7 Python, the [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) constructor in combination with a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
>>> dict((k, v * dict2[k]) for k, v in dict1.items() if k in dict2)
{'a': 15, 'b': 20}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dict2 = {'a': 15, 'b': 10, 'd': 17}

def dict_mul(d1, d2):
    d3 = dict()
    for k in d1:
        if k in d2:
            d3[k] = d1[k] * d2[k]
    return d3

print dict_mul(dict1, dict2)
```

Comment: Given that you use a `print` statement rather than a function, I think you intend your answer for Python 2.x in which case it is a poor answer as the test `if k in d2.keys():` will create a new list that contains all of `d2`'s keys every time round the outer loop. `if k in d2:` is very much to be preferred. (The same applies to the `for` loop but as that only executes once it doesn't really matter)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I should have considered more about the permorece.

Answer (score 0):

From my telephone, so bit hard to type code. This should do the trick:

```
for key, value in dict1.iteritems():
    if key in dict2:
         dict3[key] = int(dict1[key]) * int(dict2[key])
```