# How would I convert this code to a functional program (as in the paradigm)?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I have to calculate the total value f my stock based on the price per unit and number of units. I have the following code in Python:

```
prices = {
    "banana" : 4,
    "apple"  : 2,
    "orange" : 1.5,
    "pear"   : 3,
}
stock = {
    "banana" : 6,
    "apple"  : 0,
    "orange" : 32,
    "pear"   : 15,
}

for key in prices:
    print key
    print "price: %s" % prices[key]
    print "stock: %s" % stock[key]

total = 0
for key in prices:
    total = total + prices[key]*stock[key]
print total
```

And I've tried to convert it to a more functional program by replacing the last block with this:

```
def total(x):
    if len(x) == 1:
        return prices[prices.keys()[0]]*stock[prices.keys()[0]]
    else:
        return prices[prices.keys()[0]]*stock[prices.keys()[0]] + total(x[1:])

print total(prices)
```

The above code gets this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 30, in <module>
  File "python", line 28, in total
TypeError: unhashable type
```

Can someone please correct my code to a more functional programming version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's look at the imperative loop:

```
total = 0
for key in prices:
    total = total + prices[key]*stock[key]
print total
```

Examining the imperative loop, the two things that are changing every iteration are `total`, which is fine by itself, and `key`, which originates from `prices.keys()`.  So, we'll need something from those.

Let's try rewriting the imperative loop in natural language.  I'll pick English.  For each `key` in `prices` [or perhaps that should be `prices.keys()`], increase the total by `prices[key]*stock[key]`.

Since we cannot mutate total, let's rewrite the statement:

For each `key` in `prices.keys()`, increase the running total by `prices[key]*stock[key]`.

And, since the `prices.keys()` are names of fruits, let's write it again:

For each `key` in `fruitNames`, increase the running total by `prices[key]*stock[key]`.

Now, here is a mental jump I can't quite explain.  The hints were that `total` and `key` were changing through each iteration of the loop.  We can ignore `total` for now (because I am not going to confuse this further with tail-recursion-optimization).  For functional style, the `key` becomes the entire list of keys, `fruitNames`.

```
def totalRecur(fruitNames):
```

Now, let's think about the base case.  What if `prices` (and `stock`) were empty?  Well, the total would zero:

```
    if len(fruitNames) == 0:
        return 0
```

That looks just fine.  Now, what if there is only one item at position zero?

```
    key = fruitNames[0]
    return prices[key] * stock[key]
```

Because we know that `totalRecur([])` == 0, we can instead say

```
    return prices[key] * stock[key] + totalRecur([])
```

And, because the list only has one item, we know that `fruitNames[1:]` is the empty list:

```
    return prices[key] * stock[key] + totalRecur(fruitNames[1:])
```

That should give you enough information to write a good definition of `totalRecur`.

Comment: Recursion is generally to be avoided in Python. Functional != recursion.

Comment: ?? Stop being so dramatic. I'm simply stating that if you are going to give advice on how to write code in a particular language, you should not encourage the use of constructs that are generally result in inferior performance. Python is not built for recursion, there is a lot of overhead associated with allocating a new stack-frame, and there is no tail-call optimization. There is also a recursion limit. There are some cases, like walking down a tree you know isn't very deep, where the simplicity of the recursive implementation could outweigh a non-recursive implementation.

Comment: Oops! I apologize for my vague tone.  I wasn't trying to be dramatic at all.  I was agreeing with you.  I've always thought functional implied heavy use of recursion.  Then I thought about what you said, and remembered some of my troubles using lots of tail-recursion in Python 3, which still emits an error when the maximum recursion depth is exceeded.

Comment: No, no. The apologies are mine. I misread your comment as saying "StackOverflow [the site] sucks".

Comment: I got the error message wrong, anyway.  It should read `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that although, it is in Python, I don't care too much about the actual language.

Comment: You're welcome, @SomBagchi.  (1) I do hope you understand *why* it works.  Picking the arguments for a recursive function are tricky and require experience.  (2) Non-recursive functional style is better in Python, as juanpa.arrivillaga stated.  I think Marcus Vinícius Monteiro's dict comprehension is better in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

If by functional programming, you mean by using higher order functions and lambdas:

```
sum(map(lambda k, v: v * stock[k], prices.items()))
```

you get an error because the expression `x[1:]` is a dictionary, not a key

Answer (score 1):

Using generator expressions or list/set/dictionary comprehensions is very functional:

```
In [1]: prices = {
   ...:     "banana" : 4,
   ...:     "apple"  : 2,
   ...:     "orange" : 1.5,
   ...:     "pear"   : 3,
   ...: }
   ...: stock = {
   ...:     "banana" : 6,
   ...:     "apple"  : 0,
   ...:     "orange" : 32,
   ...:     "pear"   : 15,
   ...: }
   ...:

In [2]: total_value = sum(stock[k]*prices[k] for k in stock)

In [3]: total_value
Out[3]: 117.0

In [4]:
```

Comment: @GuillaumeJacquenot I disagree with the edit. Pasting the output of an interactive interpreter session is common on StackOverflow. Removing the In/Out lines actually makes it non-sensical, because the last line only works like that *in an interactive session*

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to return the value you want without side effects, avoiding state and mutation too (See [Functional Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)):

```
def total(prices, stock):
    return sum([p * stock[k] for k, p in prices.items() if k in stock])

>>> total(prices, stock)
>>> 117.0
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334783/multiplying-values-from-two-different-dictionaries-together-in-python) provided the inspiration.

Answer (score -2):

```
def total(stock):
    return sum([v*prices[k] for k,v in stock.iteritems()]) #.iteritems() is a built in method for dicts. it returns key, value pairs
                                                           #same as i, dict[i]
```