# How can I multiply dictionaries of different sizes where their keys match?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I need to multiply a dictionary `x` that has a tuple key by another dictionary `y`.  The dictionary `x` has somewhere around 1000 items while `y` has 12.  I want to multiply the values of the two dictionaries where the keys of `y` are the same as the second element of the tuple in `x`'s keys.

The dictionaries look like this, I've made these ones here shorter for this example:

```
x = {('a', 'a'): 1,
     ('a', 'b'): 0,
     ('a', 'c'): 3,
     ('a', 'd'): 2,
     ('b', 'a'): 3,
     ('b', 'b'): 2,
     ('b', 'c'): 2,
     ('b', 'd'): 1}

y = {'a': 1,
     'b': 2,
     'c': 3}

# Expected output when the two are multiplied:

z = {('a', 'a'): 1,
     ('a', 'b'): 0,
     ('a', 'c'): 9,
     ('a', 'd'): 2,
     ('b', 'a'): 3,
     ('b', 'b'): 4,
     ('b', 'c'): 6,
     ('b', 'd'): 1}
```

I have seen the solution here: [Multiplying values from two different dictionaries together in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334783/multiplying-values-from-two-different-dictionaries-together-in-python) but my situation has tuple keys in one dictionary and I'm not entirely sure how that affects the answer.

Comment: It doesn't affect the answer.

Comment: You'd need to slightly modify the answer. Unfortunately, you'd have to traverse the dictionary with tuple keys.

Comment: @Barmar I don't mean the "answer" as far as the output goes, but rather the solution for *how* to achieve `c`.  I am asking how to modify that solution to handle the tuple key

Comment: That's what I meant -- the solution should be the same.

Comment: Try it and see if it works.

Comment: @Barmar It doesn't make any sense to me why am getting this result, but when I use the method in the link I get an empty dictionary `{}`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you only have tuples as the keys in one dictionary, not both. That question is about having the same keys in both dictionaries.

Comment: `a` is a dictionary, do you really mean to have `(a, a)` as a key in itself?

Comment: No, these are simply watered down versions of what I'm actually working with for the purpose of this example. Perhaps I should share the actual dictionaries @Barmar

Comment: Just share something that's valid code, like `('a', 'a')`

Comment: @JacobMyer: if you got your answer, you should vote/accept it, so others people can benefit from your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should do it:

`{k:y.get(k[1], 1)*v for k,v in x.items()}`

`{('a', 'a'): 1,
 ('a', 'b'): 0,
 ('a', 'c'): 9,
 ('a', 'd'): 2,
 ('b', 'a'): 3,
 ('b', 'b'): 4,
 ('b', 'c'): 6,
 ('b', 'd'): 1}`

*edited to reflect the change in dictionary names*

Comment: could you just use `b.get(k[1], 1)`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to achieve your goal without using `dict-comprehension`:

```
dict1 = {('a', 'a'): 1,
 ('a', 'b'): 0,
 ('a', 'c'): 3,
 ('a', 'd'): 2,
 ('b', 'a'): 3,
 ('b', 'b'): 2,
 ('b', 'c'): 2,
 ('b', 'd'): 1}

dict2 = {'a': 1,
     'b': 2,
     'c': 3}

dict3 = {} # the result dictionary
for k, v in dict1.items():
    if k[1] in dict2: # it is the same as: if k[1] in dict2.keys()
        dict3[k] = v * dict2[k[1]]
    else:
        dict3[k] = v

print(dict3)
```

> ***Output:**
>
> ```
> {('a', 'a'): 1, ('a', 'b'): 0, ('a', 'c'): 9, ('a', 'd'): 2, ('b', 'a'): 3, ('b', 'b'): 4, ('b', 'c'): 6, ('b', 'd'): 1}
> ```

Comment: note that it's more conventional/idiomatic to write `k[1] in dict2.keys()` as `k[1] in dict2`...

Comment: @SamMason, perhaps you didn't read my code. Get a look again, you will note that I use `if k[1] in dict2.keys(): `.

Comment: I don't understand your comment! try removing your call to  `.keys()`, you should get the same output.

Comment: @SamMason, I finally get your point. I update and comment the code.

Comment: no probs! it's a useful shortcut and most codebases I've read rely on it

Comment: Yeah, I know this syntax, but I wrote the first one (`k[1] in dict2.keys()`) to specify to @JacobMyer that the comparision is based on the key.... Thank you, he will have the choice.